# How to create a wrap-around code snippet in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode10

I have a pretty large project that needs to be localized. The first thing to do is to wrap all string literals into `NSLocalizedString` and I am wonder if Xcode has a way to create "wrap-around" code snippet.

Here's what I want: say I have this code:

```
let str = "Hello World"
```

I want to select the `"Hello world"` part, then **shortcut key** and Xcode should change it to:

```
let str = NSLocalizedString("Hello World", #comment#)
```

where `#comment#` is a placeholder.

**Question:** how can I create a code snippet for something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode already supports this. Put the cursor anywhere in the string and then click the "Editor" menu. Select "Refactor" and then "Wrap in NSLocalizedString".

This options appears in a real project, not in a playground.

If you want to make this simpler you can assign a shortcut. In Xcode go to Preferences. Then select the Key Bindings tab. Find the "Wrap in NSLocalizedString" command and assign a desired shortcut.